# use "global-namespace";

Tags: php, namespaces

I just wonder if there's a way to make a class behave as if it is in global namespace using a "use" keyword, so this class would behave as namespaced class only from outside of the class.
Something like:

```
namespace wherever\somewhere\deep\deep\inside;
use \; // root namespace.. note: this doesn't work
class stuff{
//....
}
```

anyone?

Comment: Do you want your class `stuff` to be in the global namespace?

Comment: No, I want it to stay in the namespace it is in, it would break other dependencies and I cant change other dependencies, it would break autoloader. I want this to be just fast hack, just for a day or two, before I fix it properly. I've got bunch of classes like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using the global namespace won't work the way you expect.

By default, you can reference a globally namespaced class by adding a backslash -- eg `$x = new \PDO(...);`. Trying to `use \` won't change that.

If you want to drop the backslash from globally namespaced classes, you need to `use` each of them specifically. In namespaced PHP, any class reference that doesn't have a namespace is assumed to be in the current namespace, unless it is explicitly referenced by a `use` statement.

eg:

```
use \PDO, \SplFileObject;
```

now we can call `new PDO(...)` or `new SplFileObject()` without the backslash. But other global classes that aren't in the `use` would still need the backslash.

Comment: Aha, I see. I thought I can import a namespace using `use \SomeNamespace` and assumed I can do the same with global namespace. But now I'm reading, it imports it as sub-namespace of current namespace. Gosh, I should have checked this before I started moving those classes :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: agree with that 'gosh' sentiment -- moving from non-namespaced to namedspaced code in PHP is more of a chore than it needs to be. But be enouraged; once you're up and running, it's fine.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the global namespace if you use brackets like this:

```
namespace My\Space {
    function myScopedFunction() { .. }
}
namespace {
    function myGlobalFunction() { .. }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. If anyone finds a good way please do share.
I tried the below which didn't work obviously (the writeup is here http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/D0000H.php). I would find it really useful to be able to go to the root namespace this way as a lot of legacy code doesn't use namespaces.

```
$root = \_\_NAMESPACE\_\_;   // error 

namespace AA; 
function foo() { print " What AA "; }

use ($root);      // error

namespace $root;  // error can't use var

namespace ""; // error

use "/"; // error

namespace "/";   // error
```

There are a couple different issues here. One thing I thought was strange is that I can use the keyword `require_once $script_name` but I can't use the keyword `namespace $namespace_name`.