# Trying to use PHP DateTime Class with Yii2 receiving class not found errors

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

Hello I am trying to create my own custom helper class to use with Yii2.  It is going to handle times so I'll be working with PHP's DateTime class.  I have

```
<?php

namespace yii\helpers;

use Yii;

class Time
{
    public static function getTime()
    {  
    $time = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return $time->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');
    }
}
```

To test it I added
    `use yii\helpers\Time;`
to a view file and called `Time::getTime();` but Yii2 throws an ErrorException saying Class 'yii\helpers\DateTime' not found.

The php DateTime object works fine if I place the code directly into a view file and execute it so I'm not sure what my problem is.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Put a backslash in from of the class name to indicate it is in the global namespace:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Comment: Don't forget `\DateTimeZone`

Comment: Awesome answer thanks.  I don't completely understand namespaces it is a new concept to me.

Comment: Worked for Laravel5 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `use` for `DateTime`:

```
use Yii;
use DateTime;
```

See [use "global-namespace";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214293/use-global-namespace)